# How to prevent Aperture from zooming in every time I open an image

Tags: apple-aperture

In aperture, when I close an image (go back to the project or album) and select another image (by double clicking on it) the view will be 100% zoomed in to the lower left hand corner.

The only way I can prevent this from happening is by removing the zoom factor (pressing "z") before closing the image.

Also if I zoom out (still zoomed but further out) before closing the image, the next image will appear zoomed right into the corner,

This does not seem like normal behavior for an Apple app to me. Is there some way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why are you double-clicking to select a new image?  Is it really "zoomed" (using magnification) or merely taking up most of the window, with no "film strip" below it?  Try using the "v" key to rotate between views, and try single-clicking instead of double-clicking to choose a new image to look at.  For what it's worth, I never "close" images, and when I'm zoomed in, I can switch to other images (single-clicking or with arrow keys) and it maintains the current zoom level, which is generally what I want.

Comment: is it possible you have some kind of customised shortcut where double-click zooms? or are accidentally scrolling/pinching while clicking? do you get the same zoom problem if you just select the new image (single click) and switch to single-image view (from the toolbar)... also what version of Aperture?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that configured in Aperture. I'm using Aperture 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you ever find an answer for this?  If not, it's pretty simple.  Just open an image and if it automatically goes to 100% then just push "z".  Now close the image.  next time you open any image you should be back to normal.  Good luck.

Comment: That's usually what I do. I guess this is as close to a solution as I'm going to get :-)

Comment: To add to Dave's answer, think of the "Z" button as a toggle. If you press it once, it's "on" until you press it again to turn it 'off'.